Langchain SQL Agents using Knowledge Graphs
I'm designing custom SQL agents using LangGraph to have more control over the agent flow. I need to define a sequence of tool executions in a knowledge graph and ensure the system executes them correctly. This is my current understanding of how the flow should work:

Start with the list_tables tool.
Based on the output, decide to proceed to step 2 or end the process.
Use the get_table_info tool.
Depending on the result, move to step 3, 4, or end the process.
Apply the filter_word tool.
This should always lead to step 4.
Execute the execute_query tool.
Based on the output, decide to proceed to step 5 or end the process.
Finally, use the graph_tool to complete the process.

I need help with the following:

How do I define and structure this sequence of tool executions in a knowledge graph using LangGraph?
How should I integrate LLMs to parse inputs between each tool node effectively?
Are there any best practices or examples available that demonstrate a similar implementation?

Any detailed explanations, code snippets, or examples would be highly appreciated!
